# Why glibc binary is called libc.so.6 not a libc.so.1 or libc.so.4?

Tags: linux, glibc

The modern glibc binary is called libc.so.6 in Linux. Why is "6" used here? The libc.so.1 or libc.so.8 can be good names too IMHO.

Wikipedia gives some history at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_C_Library but doesn't explain fully

> In the early 1990s, the developers of the Linux kernel forked glibc. Their fork, called "Linux libc", was maintained separately for years and released versions 2 through 5.
>
> When FSF released glibc 2.0 in January 1997, ....  At this point, the Linux kernel developers discontinued their fork and returned to using FSF's glibc.[6]
>
> The last used version of Linux libc used the internal name (soname) libc.so.5. Following on from this, glibc 2.x on Linux uses the soname libc.so.6

Comment: They're version numbers, and 1 through 5 have been used by previous editions.

Comment: glibc version number is like 2.8, not a glibc 5 or glibc 6

Comment: There's also the original non-GNU libc editions as well.

Comment: Note: the one without `.6` is a linker script: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13790973/what-is-the-difference-between-lib-i386-linux-gnu-libc-so-6-lib-x86-64-linux

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those [SONAMEs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soname) have already been used. Since the new version of the library presents a break in the interface, a new major SONAME number must be used for it.

Comment: Does every new version break an interface?

Comment: Of glibc? No. They simply modify the implementation or add new capabilities to the interface.

Comment: Will it be a libc.so.7 sometime? When?

Comment: When a new libc is written that is meant to be parallel-installable with glibc.

Comment: Now they can version individual symbols so it is much less likely that a change will ever again be needed to the libc major version, unless it is some kind of complete overhaul of the whole library.