# What is the difference between /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6, /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 and /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so?

Tags: gcc, 64-bit, libc

I installed Matlab in my Linux Mint 14 Nadia (a uname -a shows: Linux Ideapad-Z570 3.5.0-17-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 9 19:31:23 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux) and when calling it from the command line I would get a: "/lib64/libc.so not found".

I followed the help on mathworks by making a link in /lib64 as:

```
ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 .
```

That solved the issue.

Now, if I do a locate of this library I get:

```
locate "libc.so"
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so
```

I will be compiling with gcc in this computer and I would like to have full 64bit compilations. What does exactly mean to have all these different libc.so libraries? which one will the gnu compiler be using? do I need to do anything different with gcc to compile for 64 bits?

I would also love to optimize as much as I can for my new i7 core!!!

Comment: user1889975, Hi. Are you sure that all 3 `libc.so`s are different? Do an `ls -l` on then to find symlinks. Also, there was a change recently in default path to 32/64bit libs on mixed 32/64 bit systems (from `/lib64` to `/lib/tr-ip-le/`), check this page for addtional info http://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/TheCaseForMultiarch

Comment: I did check and they are NOT symlinks. Thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

This is is 32-bit version of the library.

> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

This is the 64-bit version of the library.

Both are usually symbolic links to the actual library file, which will usually be named according to the glibc release number, for example `libc-2.15.so`

> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so

This is not a library, but a linker script file, which refers to the above symlinks.

Why do we need all these:

First, regardless of libc version installed, the linker will always search for `libc.so`, because the compiler driver will always pass to the linker the `-lc` options. The name `libc` stays the same and denotes to most recent version of the library.

The symlinks `libc.so.6` are named after the *soname* of the library, which, more or less corresponds to the ABI version of the library. The executables, linked against `libc.so` in fact contain runtime dependencies on `libc.so.6`.

If we imagine the someday a grossly ABI incompatible libc is released, it's soname could be named `libc.so.7`, for example and this version coukld coexists with the older `libc.so.6` version, thus executables linked against one or the other can coexist in the same system,

And finally, the name `libc-2.15.so` refers to the libc release, when you install a new libc package, the name will change to `libc-2.16.so`. Provided that it is binary compatible with the previous release, the `libc.so.6` link will stay named that way and the existing executables will continue to work.

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped me a lot to understand the why.

Comment: Why do they also name the linker script with `.so`? That's confusing.

Answer (score 3):

To find which one to use, you have to first find the order that `ld` (the linker) uses to find libraries, like so:

```
ld --verbose | grep SEARCH
```

For me it gave me this output:

```
SEARCH_DIR("/usr/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib64"); SEARCH_DIR("/usr/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("/usr/lib"); SEARCH_DIR("/usr/local/lib");
```

This means that on my computer, `ld` looks in these directories, in order:

1. /usr/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib64
2. /usr/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib
3. /usr/lib
4. /usr/local/lib

So if libc was in /usr/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib64, and libc was also in /usr/lib, it would use the /usr/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib64 version, because it was listed first.

Comment: Very interesting and helpful. Thank you. In my case it lists "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" first so I'm good to compile 64 bit code.
Now, I want to understand this fully. Why did my linux distribution installed this library in several different locations then?

Comment: @Alejandro, no problem! If it's solved, could you mark it as such?

Comment: Sorry, but I still want to know the why the many locations? are these files the same copied over and over? there may be a reason for this I guess.

I will mark it as solved when I get these answers. Thank you again!

Comment: Yes, there is. From what I see, the first result of `locate ...` (/lib/i386...) is the 32-bit version of libc (needed for running 32-bit applications), the second entry (/lib/x86_64...) is the 64-bit version of libc, and the third entry is a symlink to the second. I'm not quite sure why the symlink is created, but I think it has something to do with compatibility for other programs or compilers.

Comment: Actually the third one is NOT a symlink. But I see what you are saying

Comment: Oh sorry, I reread your post. The _second_ one is a symlink, and it _should_ point to the third one (if it doesn't, you might have problems)

Answer (score 1):

The symlink you created will have no effect whatsoever on GCC. The 32-bit version is only used when you compile using the `-m32` GCC flag. GCC will not attempt to generate 32-bit binaries unless you specifically tell it to (by using that flag.)

Comment: Thank you, very clear for the point regarding if gcc would compile 64 bit code by default.