# How to create a symbolic link to a linker script?

Tags: gcc, linker, arm, symlink

I had a problem that the linker is not finding some symbolic links to some libraries:

```
ld: warning: library.so.1, needed by libSDL2.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

I had this problem for 4 libraries: `libdl`, `libm`, `libc`, `libpthread`.

I managed to solve it for the first 2 libraries by creating symbolic links to them by [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html):

`libdl.so.1 ==> libdl.so` (`libdl.so.1` is a symbolic link for `libdl.so`)

`libm.so.1 ==> libm.so` (`libm.so.1` is a symbolic link for `libm.so`)

This however didn't work for the other 2 libraries (still having the exact same warning).

The problematic libraries (`libc.so` and `libpthread.so`) differ from the others in that they are linker scripts (rather than binary files). For example here's `libc.so`:

```
/* GNU ld script
   Use the shared library, but some functions are only in
   the static library, so try that secondarily.  */
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-littlearm)
GROUP ( /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc_nonshared.a  AS_NEEDED ( /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 ) )
```

So my guess is that the symbolic links for them need to be different (or created differently...)

Any ideas?

I'm using this compiler: [arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc](https://launchpad.net/linaro-toolchain-binaries) to cross compile something for ARM that was written on Windows.

Comment: Look at an equivalent (but [more recent](http://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/)) Linaro toolchain on my Linux box, it seems like you're looking at `<sysroot>/usr/lib/<arch>/*.so`, which I see are just links back to the real `<sysroot>/lib/<arch>/*.so.<n>` anyway. Note that bodging filenames still won't change the fact that [libc.so.6 is intentionally not libc.so.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soname), though; even if you do trick the linker I wouldn't count on it actually running successfully.

Comment: The answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13790973/what-is-the-difference-between-lib-i386-linux-gnu-libc-so-6-lib-x86-64-linux) offer a little more background on multiarch paths and versioning.

Comment: I think I need a more recent SDL that uses `libc.so.6` instead of `libc.so.1`. I just can't find `libc.so.1` anywhere; I found only `libc.so.6`.